# Detect current page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if Javascript can detect what page the user is on. Say for example that the user is on a "About" or "Contact" page, can JavaScript check if the pathway is "/About" or "/Contact" and then take action accordingly ?
How would that code look like?
I appreciate if anyone could give me a code sample

Comment: Yes, you can use `document.location.href`.

Comment: `if(location.href=='/contacts')document.body.innerHTML="";` check the location, set the body html to empty string.

Comment: When you searched on Google for "javascript get current URL", you didn't find *anything*?

Comment: Look, I [googled your title](https://www.google.com/search?q=Detect%20current%20page%20with%20JavaScript) and came up with 9,640,000 results, and everything on the first page is exactly what people here are telling you to do...

Comment: So you people who are telling OP to search, do you not know how to close questions as a duplicate? You people sound very rude to a new user here.

Comment: it's been flagged...

Comment: @epascarello, done. But pray tell, why did you insist on answering this instead of closing as a duplicate? Surely a user with your reputation can find one quickly enough.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can get the URL by doing this:

```
window.location.href
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what age they are on, it really depends on the url structure. But you will get the information with `window.location.pathname`

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
switch(pathname) {
   case "/home" :
       console.log("home");
       break;
   case "/game" :
       console.log("game");
       break;
}
```